# iOS: Changing the background image on tap gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the tap gesture set up and it when I tap it in the simulator the NSLog fires, so I'm sure it's hitting it:

```
@implementation CoolController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ...

    UITapGestureRecognizer *backgroundTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(backgroundTapped)];
    backgroundTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:backgroundTapRecognizer];
}

- (void) backgroundTapped {
    NSLog(@"cool"); // <-- this fires when I tap it twice
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"table-2"]]];
}
```

However, the image in the background doesn't change. Do I need to call another method to update the UI?

Comment: Try setting the `backgroundColor` in `viewDidLoad` and see if it works

Comment: Usually, you don't need to call anything more. But try setNeedDisplay. Or try with different images?

Comment: Try forcing that into the main thread (i.e): `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"table-2"]]];
} });`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

- (void) backgroundTapped: **(id)sender**

Answer (score 0):

Try this in viewDidLoad and check if color changes:

> [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"table-2.png"]]];

Add extension to your image png/jpg whatever it is. Hope it helps